# Replay log using WCF technology

Tags: .net, wcf, iclientmessageinspector

I need to replay some logs saved in JSON in .NET with WCF technology. The software use IClientMessageInspector to obtain the logs and
save them in JSON afterwards. So, I need to get this logs and inject them again. To do this,I did something similar as I did when I obtains the logs.
I did extend the WCF EndPoint and modify the message with new parameters. Here is the code :

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
            {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(record.Message.ToString());
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();

                    XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms);
                    doc.WriteTo(writer);
                    writer.Flush();
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
                    Message newReply = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, null, reader);
                    newReply.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(request);
                    request = newReply;
            }
```

This function seems to have the right values. But, It can call many differents functions depending on the json file. To be able to go into that "BeforeSendRequest" method,
I need to call a existing method for example :

```
m_MyService.XXX();
```

And because I modify it in "BeforeSendRequest", it shoudln't matter which function I'm calling here.
But, it does return me the error :

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Erreur lors de la désérialisation du corps du message de demande pour l'opération 'XXX'. OperationFormatter a rencontré un corps de Message non valide. Type de nœud 'Element' attendu avec le nom 'XXX' et l'espace de noms 'http://tempuri.org/'. Type de nœud 'Element' trouvé avec le nom 'YYY' et l'espace de noms 'http://tempuri.org/'. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: OperationFormatter a rencontré un corps de Message non valide. Type de nœud 'Element' attendu avec le nom 'XXX' et l'espace de noms 'http://tempuri.org/'. Type de nœud 'Element' trouvé avec le nom 'YYY' et l'espace de noms 'http://tempuri.org/'.
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

It looks like it doesn't like when the method call isn't m_MyService.YYY();

Comment: the DataContract should be as same as what you've specified in the Operation. Here your DataContract is 'xxx' but you are modifying it to 'yyy'. Try sending instance of 'xxx'

Comment: Mmmh I'm not sure i've understood correctly 'xxx' is a method. And if I call m_MyService.YYY(); first it will work but only when the method loaded in BeforeSendRequest is m_MyService.YYY(); if I call any other method than YYY, it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, hope it can help. I just had to modify the "action" in the header. So just add this line:

```
newReply.Headers.Action = "desiredcontent";
```